# Ruby Net HTTP Call SSL Version Inconsistencies

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl, net-http, sslv3

I have the following code:

```
 http = Net::HTTP.new(parsed_url.host, 443)
 http.use_ssl = true
 http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
 protocol = "https"
```

In a single day thousands of calls are made. The server receiving the request has disabled `SSLv3` because of the Poodle Vulnerability. The actual http call is wrapped in a timeout block that waits for 8 seconds for a response from the server. This code executes the request successfully 99% of the time, however occasionally a timeout occurs. After working with the Amazon support team, it was determined that all the calls which timed-out, were made using `SSLv3`, which caused a handshake error. All the successful calls used `TLSv1.1` or `TLSv1.2`.

Can anyone shed some light, on the what might cause ruby to occasionally use SSLv3 in its attempts ? For additional context, this ruby code is being used with Nginx / Phusion Passenger, and being run on an Amazon Ec2 instance.

Comment: The explanation does not make much sense: a handshake error will not cause a timeout but instead close the connection immediately. But typical problems for infrequent timeouts are the attempt to use non-blocking SSL sockets with select, see for example https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8875. It might be, that Net::HTTP is doing something like this internally.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have updated the explanation a bit. The http call is wrapped in a 8 second timeout block.

Comment: *`http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`* - ice picks in my eyes. See this Ruby question on how to avoid `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`: [SSLError: hostname “W.X.Y.Z” does not match the server certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27795484/608639)