# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError hostname does not match the server certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, openssl, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.9.3

I'm trying to make an API call to SmartDebit a 3rd party direct debit processing website from my Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 2 app.

I'm getting this error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError·hostname does not match the server certificate
```

The error occurs here: "https://onepointnine.survivalinternational.org/donate" when trying to make a direct debit payment.

As far as I can tell my SSL certificate is correctly set up and valid for this hostname, Smart Debit have confirmed that the error doesn't refer to their endpoint.

Also, the error can't be to do with certificate verification because I already have this code in an initializer (n.b. I realise this isn't best practice, I've inherited this codebase):

```
class Net::HTTP
  alias_method :old_initialize, :initialize
  def initialize(*args)
    old_initialize(*args)
    @ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
    @ssl_context.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  end
end
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: We can't test the link without making a donation. Perhaps it would be better to tell us the URL wired into the button. Also see [SSLError: hostname “W.X.Y.Z” does not match the server certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27795484/608639). There's no material difference between using a DNS name as the hostname or an IP address as the hostname. The end-entity (server) certificate must has a Subject Alternate Name with the name you are using to connect.

Comment: The endpoint i'm trying to hit is https://secure.ddprocessing.co.uk/api/ddi/variable/create

Comment: The reason I think it's a different problem to the question you've linked to is that that is dealing with certificate verification, but I assume i'm already bypassing that by using OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE mentioned above (even though I know it's bad practice). N.B. You can actually test the link without making a donation, there's a confirmation screen. Thank you for your help.